# Elements within a face of a 3d css cube cannot be selected. Strange

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, firefox, chromium

I am building a 3d css cube menu. Code [here](http://jsfiddle.net/lcristianiim/kvatm644/1/).

```
<button id="btn">flip button</button>    
<div class="signup-viewport">
    <div id="cube" class="cube animation">
        <div class="front">front <a href="">front link</a></div>
        <div class="back">Back</div>
        <div class="left">Left</div>
        <div class="right">Right <a href="">right link</a></div>
        <div class="bottom">Bottom</div>
        <div class="top">Top</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

When the face is flipped by the 'flip button' button, the link from the right side of the cube cannot be clicked.

Any ideas why?
In firefox the link works, but on chrome and chromium does not.

Comment: It looks like you're not adding the `left-rotate` class anywhere for when the button is clicked again?

Comment: @Sterling Archer the button just rotate the cube to the right side. On front side the link can be clicked, but after the flip button is clicked the link from the right side can not be clicked. If you hover the mouse on this link the cursor does not turns to pointer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After very very much struggle I finally managed to work around the not clickable and not selectable problem.

To make the sides of the cube selectable the 'perspective' property is needed (as @Cedric Reichenbach sugested); but as a side effect pixalation occures due to the perspective rendering. I tried to get rid of pixalation using a big perspective number (10000px), but the pixalation was still there. So by increasing the perspective number, the rendering z plane is going 'further away' giving the appearance of less perspective.

After two days of experimenting all kinds of stuff the way I 'tricked' perspective was by using an extremely large number for perspective. (`perspective: 10000000px;`) Now the pixalation effect is gone and the sides of the cube are clickable and selectable.

[Here](http://jsfiddle.net/lcristianiim/kvatm644/7/) is a demonstration of the solution.

Answer (score 1):

It's because your surfaces had a `height` of `0`, causing the text to be rendered into padding area. Firefox and Chrome seem to treat such elements differently in terms of mouse events.

If you use `height: auto`, it works as expected, but you should take care that heights remain consistent with changing content.

Here's your modified [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kvatm644/4/) demonstrating it.

**Update:**

Apparently, chrome behaves differently on different OS' (or versions).

However, the problem seems to be related to 3D nature of your transformations (`transform-style: preserve-3D`). When setting an explicit perspective, it works on my machine, though still a bit shaky.

[Updated JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kvatm644/6/)

You might also notice that everything looks a bit blurry now, since the 3D transforms "detach" content from the pixel grid by virtually lifting planes closer to the viewer.

Comment: thank you for the answer. I've visited the link but it seems that I still can not click the 'right link'. I have used that height hack in order to get the height=width for responsive matters. Hope I will get away with it with height = 0.

Comment: That's weird; I had tested on Linux and it worked, but on Windows, it seems to behave differently... Well, you could always use another element inside with absolute positioning and z-index > 1 to not mess with the parent's height.

Comment: You are very cool. The only problem now remains that every thing I put on the sides of the cube are a little pixalated because of the perspective. Do you know a solution for that? Thank you!

Comment: Well, it's a 3D effect after all, meaning browsers somehow need to render content like textures (imagine a 3D game), so sharpness depends heavily on of anti-aliasing and texture filtering, which can heavily impact performance. I don't think you can tell browsers what rendering quality to use here (not sure though).

Comment: The thing is that I need to put there an impeccable form. So if the form will look pixalated it will not be ok. I will continue to find a solution without the pixalated efect. If I will find the solution I will write it here.

Comment: I guess the only solution then is to create transforms without `preserve-3D`.

Comment: check out the workaround I found. Thanks for all the sugestions and help. [demonstration](http://jsfiddle.net/lcristianiim/kvatm644/7/)